# Javascript on click event not working within a function but works in document.ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inside my document.ready(), I have a few buttons (a, b, c) and when clicked they call a specific method. However, when I click on button (d), I need buttons (a,b,c) to stop calling their specific methods and do nothing when clicked. I tried using the preventDefault() method, but it did not work. Someone please help! Thanks in advance :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  ...

  // my buttons (a,b,c) which call method fA
  $("#a, #b, #c").on("click", fA);

  // my button (d) which call method fB
  $('#d').on("click", fB);

  ...
});

// When button (d) is clicked, I want buttons a,b,c to be non-clickable and this method should not be called.
function fA() { 
  // does a AJAX request
  $.ajax({
    url: ...,
    data: ...,
    dataType: "script"
  });
}

function fB() {
  $("#a, #b, #c").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // THIS IS NOT WORKING!
  });
  ... 
  //Does its own unique AJAX request
}
```

Comment: you could disabled buttons: `$("#a, #b, #c").prop('disabled',true)`

Comment: Your "solution" doesn't work because simply add a new event handler to the buttons. The existing one won't be replaced, both will be called when you click any of those buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `.on()`, event handlers are not *replaced* — they're *added*.  Any element may have many event handlers for the same event. You're successfully adding new "click" handlers, but the old ones are still there too.

You can use `.off()` to remove *all* handlers for a particular event.

```
$('#a, #b, #c').off("click");
```

If you want some existing handlers to be temporarily disabled, you can either set the "disabled" property directly on the elements involved (provided they're the right kinds of elements), or else use some flagging mechanism of your own.

As an example of "flagging" to know when the handlers should/shouldn't operate, you can use a class:

```
function fA() { 
  if ($(this).hasClass('inactive')) return;

  // does a AJAX request
  $.ajax({
    url: ...,
    data: ...,
    dataType: "script"
  });
}

function fB() {
  $("#a, #b, #c").addClass('inactive');
  // ...
```

When you want the "A" function to start working again, you can just remove that class:

```
$('#a, #b, #c').removeClass('inactive');
```

Comment: This works great, however now lets say when I have a button e and it calls method fC, this method should re-enable the click event and buttons a,b,c should call method fA again. I tried using $('#a, #b, #c').on("click"); but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Rahul yes, `.off()` removes all assigned handlers; they're removed and thrown away, essentially. That's what I meant by keeping a flag around. I'll extend the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change function fB to:

```
function fB() {
  $("#a, #b, #c").off("click");
  ... 
  //Does its own unique AJAX request
}
```